# Jekyll is not showing gifs

Tags: html, ruby, jekyll, gif

I'm trying to put a gif onto my jekyll site.

I've tried the standard

```
![yay](assets/Animation/run.gif)
```

as well as:

```
<figure>
    <IMG SRC="assets/Animation/run.gif">
</figure>
```

but each time I just get the little blue question mark icon saying it can't find it? All the stuff I can find online seems to suggest it should 'just work'.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

[Page in question](https://ash.optimalbuild.com/linux/macos/2018/10/23/Solving-animations-for-everyone.html)

Comment: Could you show dir structure of jekyll project (esp. the part when `run.gif` is located)?

Comment: If you look at the console output, is there an error with the file location it is looking for the file in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using a **"relative to current path"** url : **assets/Animation/run.gif**

On a page with url like **protocol://domain.tld/cat1/cat2/year/month/day/**, this will resolve based on current path :

**protocol://domain.tld/cat1/cat2/year/month/day/assets/Animation/run.gif**

Which is wrong.

You must call you assets with **"relative to root"** urls :

```
![yay](/assets/Animation/run.gif)
```

or

```
<img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/Animation/run.gif">
```

Comment: Cheers! I thought that omitting the first "/" would make it relative.

Comment: Edited my answer.